# Creating a AAR Library in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, aar

making the AAR library in Android Studio I follow the link-

http://dominoc925.blogspot.in/2015/09/how-to-create-and-use-android-archive.html

I follow same as written in this link.
as

1. creating android application selecting no activity.
2. creating a module in it.
3. creating a java class in which log class.
4. and the go to the gradle panel and click on the assemblerelease.

after doing all these according to the link there must be x-debug.rar and x-release.rar files in the output folder. But in my case only debug.rar is generated. I need the release file.

Please help me out of there. if there is another method or link kindly tell me and also about how to include this rar file to the another android application

**NOTE**

> Android studio version-2.2.1
>
> gradle version -2.2.1

Comment: I did the same things before few days ago.It's working fine .any way you can cross verify with your existing application that is already build in your android studio .first clean and rebuild then just follow step 13 and onwards ,mention in blog.

Comment: I have done this also as clean and rebuild but nothing happen. I have a doubt - can it happen because of version variation?

Comment: I'm not sure .but why you can not try in to your existing working application rather than creating new app

Comment: This task is given to me. I have to make a Library of existing code written in C language so that i can use it in Android application development. do you have any method so that i can create any library file using the C language code.

Comment: There isn't any particular function to make jar . you just have to make use of your existing project in to another project (main project) .next step is clean and rebuild your main project.you will get .jar of your library project in to build->intermidates->bundle->debug->classes.jar  <= here classes.jar is the file you want .

Comment: I have only c code. if i have to create its jar file then again use of JNI come. Can you elaborate how to do? I am really too confused.

Comment: I am talking about projects written in java , in case of c language you have to refer NDK and jni .I never tried to create .jar of any c language code . let me find it for you in my free time . get back to you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

choose Gradle window from right side. 
then expand your lib gradle , tasks , bulid then double click on build task . now you have release arr in build/outputs/aar directory